# Any Idea Why This HTTP Request is Posting Twice?

Tags: asp-classic, httprequest

When I call the function below, it response writes once as expected (last line of function).

But on the api logger of the website being posted to, it shows **two** posts. Not only that, but the first post is missing the authentication header.

Would somebody be kind enough to look over this code and tell me if I'm doing anything daft?

```
private function PostToWebsite(data, url)
    Dim  httpRequest, postResponse
    Set httpRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    httpRequest.Open "POST", url, False, "un", "pw"
    httpRequest.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"     
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", len(data)
    httpRequest.Send data
    if httpRequest.status = 201 then    
        PostToWebsite = "ok/" & httpRequest.getResponseHeader("Location")
    elseif httpRequest.status = 400 then
        PostToWebsite= "error/Http 400 error: " & httpRequest.responseText 
    elseif httpRequest.status = 401 then 
        PostToWebsite= "error/Http 401 error: " & httpRequest.responseText 
    else    
        PostToWebsite= "error/Unknown status in PostToWebsite"
    end if
    Set httpRequest = nothing

    RESPONSE.WRITE  PostToWebsite   'this line writes only once

end function
```

Comment: If there's no obvious error in the code above, would somebody be able to give me the heads up and say 'it looks ok to me'?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there was a comma missing from the JSON payload.  Once I fixed that it worked fine.

*My new question is:  why on earth would that generate a double post, as opposed to a single one that failed?!*

Comment: I am having the same issue, have you found what is the problem ?

Comment: I never figured out why that behavior occurred.  All I would say is to check the response for any errors - sorry I can't help more